# pandas Subtracting after groupby mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size':['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
                   'value': [2,3,1,4,5,1,0,2,3,]})
size value
A    2
A    3
B    1
B    4
B    5
C    1
C    0
C    2
C    3
```

and I want to group by size  and then subtract then mean

```
df.groupby('size').agg({'value':'mean'})

      mean value
size          
A     2.5000
B     3.3333
C     1.5000
```

I want my output to look something like this:

```
size value mean_diff
A    2     -0.5000
A    3     0.5000
B    1     -2.3333
B    4     0.6667
B    5     1.6667
C    1     -2.3333
C    0     -1.500
C    2     0.5000
C    3     1.5000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can [`Groupby+transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and then [`subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].sub(df.groupby('size')['value'].transform('mean'))
#or df.groupby('size')['value'].transform(lambda x: x - x.mean()) as sammywemmy suggests
print(df)
```

---

```
  size     value
0    A -0.500000
1    A  0.500000
2    B -2.333333
3    B  0.666667
4    B  1.666667
5    C -0.500000
6    C -1.500000
7    C  0.500000
8    C  1.500000
```

Comment: u could just pass it with an anonymous function , makes it simpler IMHO... 
    df.groupby('size').transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())

Comment: @sammywemmy - simplier, but slowier

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks , edited with your suggestion, lambda should  be a little slower though

Comment: True , it is slower.